# Number theory primes and Goldbach conjecture

Tags: number-theory

We all know the famous Goldbach conjecture . I have found a statement says that for any even integer n >50there exists a prime p  <√n such that n-p is again a prime . has any body seen this before or I am the first person to notice this conjecture which looks a little stronger than Goldbach conjecture or may be equivalent to Goldbach conjecture ... Any ideas or any thing which can be put forward to prove this ?

Comment: Where did you find the statement?

Comment: I myself ... I checked a lot of even numbers and I have always found a prime less than nsquareroot for which even number-that prime is again prime

Answer (score 2):

It is not certain that there is any prime at all between $n$ and $n-\sqrt{n}$.
This is stronger than Legendre's conjecture, which has not been proven, and which claims there is a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.

Comment: It's not certain but I have checked alot of even numbers which have always this property but I cannot prove it of course

Comment: OP's question only concerns even $n$. Are you sure it would imply Legendre's conjecture?

Comment: If $n$ is even, then $n^2+2n$ is even, so OP implies there is a prime between $n^2+2n$ and $n^2+2n-\sqrt{n^2+2n}>n^2$.  If $n$ is odd, OP implies there is a prime between $(n+1)^2$ and $(n+1)^2-(n+1)>n^2$.

Comment: Do you think what I claim implies legendre s conjecture also ?

Comment: @Mathslovershah Yes, it implies Legendre's conjecture. The comment above shows how.

Comment: But we can't prove it unfortunately...and am I the first person to claim this ?

Comment: This site describes a search up to 4000000000000000000. http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/goldbach.html  They suggest $\log n\log n\log\log n$ which is tighter than your bound.